# Consuming an IEnumerable multiple times in one pass

Tags: c#, ienumerable

Is it possible to write a higher-order function that causes an `IEnumerable` to be consumed multiple times but in only one pass and without reading all the data into memory? [*See Edit below for a clarification of what I'm looking for.*]

For example, in the code below the enumerable is `mynums` (onto which I've tagged a `.Trace()` in order to see how many times we enumerate it).  The goal is figure out if it has any numbers greater than 5, as well as the sum of all of the numbers.  A function which processes an enumerable twice is `Both_TwoPass`, but it enumerates it twice.  In contrast `Both_NonStream` only enumerates it once, but at the expense of reading it into memory.  In principle it is possible carry out both of these tasks in a single pass and in a streaming fashion as shown by `Any5Sum`, but that is specific solution.  Is it possible to write a function with the same signature as `Both_*` but that is the best of both worlds?

(It seems to me that this should be possible using threads.  Is there a better solution using, say, `async`?)

### Edit

Below is a clarification regarding what I'm looking for. What I've done is included a very down-to-earth description of each property in square brackets.

I'm looking for a function `Both` with the following characteristics:

1. It has signature `(S1, S2) Both<T, S1, S2>(this IEnumerable<T> tt, Func<IEnumerable<T>, S1>, Func<IEnumerable<T>, S2>)` (and produces the "right" output!)
2. It only iterates the first argument, `tt`, once. [What I mean by this is that when passed `mynums` (as defined below) it only outputs `mynums: 0 1 2 ...` *once*. This precludes function `Both_TwoPass`.]
3. It processes the data from the first argument, `tt`, in a streaming fashion. [What I mean by this is that, for example, there is insufficient memory to store all the items from `tt` in memory simultaneously, thus precluding function `Both_NonStream`.]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    static class Extensions
    {
        public static IEnumerable<T> Trace<T>(this IEnumerable<T> tt, string msg = "")
        {
            Console.Write(msg);
            try
            {
                foreach (T t in tt)
                {
                    Console.Write(" {0}", t);
                    yield return t;
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                Console.WriteLine('.');
            }
        }

        public static (S1, S2) Both_TwoPass<T, S1, S2>(this IEnumerable<T> tt, Func<IEnumerable<T>, S1> f1, Func<IEnumerable<T>, S2> f2)
        {
            return (f1(tt), f2(tt));
        }

        public static (S1, S2) Both_NonStream<T, S1, S2>(this IEnumerable<T> tt, Func<IEnumerable<T>, S1> f1, Func<IEnumerable<T>, S2> f2)
        {
            var tt2 = tt.ToList();
            return (f1(tt2), f2(tt2));
        }

        public static (bool, int) Any5Sum(this IEnumerable<int> ii)
        {
            int sum = 0;
            bool any5 = false;
            foreach (int i in ii)
            {
                sum += i;
                any5 |= i > 5; // or: if (!any5) any5 = i > 5;
            }
            return (any5, sum);
        }

    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var mynums = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Trace("mynums:");
            Console.WriteLine("TwoPass: (any > 5, sum) = {0}", mynums.Both_TwoPass(tt => tt.Any(k => k > 5), tt => tt.Sum()));
            Console.WriteLine("NonStream: (any > 5, sum) = {0}", mynums.Both_NonStream(tt => tt.Any(k => k > 5), tt => tt.Sum()));
            Console.WriteLine("Manual: (any > 5, sum) = {0}", mynums.Any5Sum());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In your first sentence I think you mean that the _elements_ of the `IEnumerable` are consumed (processed) multiple times while the `IEnumerable` is only consumed/enumerated once.  As for your parenthetical about threads and `async`, I think enumerating only once is a separate goal than what thread(s) happens to process the enumerated data.  I'm not sure threading simplifies anything here; you'd have to have one thread do the enumeration and queue the data for each processing thread to handle, which would only make sense if that processing is much more CPU-intensive than what you've shown here.

Comment: The way threading might work, is loosely as follows: create two special-purpose `IEnumerable`s, `tt1` and `tt2` that are backed by `tt` and then start a thread to execute `f1(tt1)` and another to execute `f2(tt2)` (and collect the results when they are done. `tt1` and `tt2` would produce the same items at `tt`, but, importantly, would be interlocked so they would cause an item to be read from `tt` and the each of `tt1` and `tt2` would yield that item. I think I may just need to have a go at writing this to know how feasible it really is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60963484/consuming-an-ienumerable-multiple-times-in-one-pass#comment107891577_60963484) and [I](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60963484/consuming-an-ienumerable-multiple-times-in-one-pass#comment107857426_60963484) are describing the same thing in the comments.  There is no need to create such a "special-purpose `IEnumerable`", though, because the [`BlockingCollection<>` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1) already exists for such producer-consumer scenarios.  You'd use it as follows...

- Create a `BlockingCollection<>` for each consuming function (i.e. `tt1` and `tt2`).

  - By default, a `BlockingCollection<>` wraps a [`ConcurrentQueue<>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1), so the elements will arrive in FIFO order.
  - To satisfy your requirement that only one element be held in memory at a time, `1` will be specified for the [bounded capacity](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1.boundedcapacity).  Note that this capacity is per collection, so with two collections there will be up to two queued elements at any given moment.
  - Each collection will hold the input elements for that consumer.
- Create a thread/task for each consuming function.

  - The thread/task will simply call [`GetConsumingEnumerator()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1.getconsumingenumerable) for its input collection, pass the resulting `IEnumerable<>` to its consuming function, and return that result.

    - `GetConsumingEnumerable()` does just as its name implies: it creates an `IEnumerable<>` that *consumes* (removes) elements from the collection.  If the collection is empty, enumeration will block until an element is added.  [`CompleteAdding()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1.completeadding) is called once the producer is finished, which allows the consuming enumerator to exit when the collection empties.
- The producer enumerates the `IEnumerable<>`, `tt`, and adds each element to both collections.  This is the only time that `tt` is enumerated.

  - [`BlockingCollection<>.Add()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1.add) will block if the collection has reached its capacity, preventing the entirety of `tt` from being buffered in-memory.
- Once `tt` has been fully enumerated, `CompleteAdding()` is called on each collection.
- Once each consumer thread/task has completed, their results are returned.

Here's what that looks like in code...

```cs
public static (S1, S2) Both<T, S1, S2>(this IEnumerable<T> tt, Func<IEnumerable<T>, S1> tt1, Func<IEnumerable<T>, S2> tt2)
{
    const int MaxQueuedElementsPerCollection = 1;

    using (BlockingCollection<T> collection1 = new BlockingCollection<T>(MaxQueuedElementsPerCollection))
    using (Task<S1> task1 = StartConsumerTask(collection1, tt1))
    using (BlockingCollection<T> collection2 = new BlockingCollection<T>(MaxQueuedElementsPerCollection))
    using (Task<S2> task2 = StartConsumerTask(collection2, tt2))
    {
        foreach (T element in tt)
        {
            collection1.Add(element);
            collection2.Add(element);
        }

        // Inform any enumerators created by .GetConsumingEnumerable()
        // that there will be no more elements added.
        collection1.CompleteAdding();
        collection2.CompleteAdding();

        // Accessing the Result property blocks until the Task<> is complete.
        return (task1.Result, task2.Result);
    }

    Task<S> StartConsumerTask<S>(BlockingCollection<T> collection, Func<IEnumerable<T>, S> func)
    {
        return Task.Run(() => func(collection.GetConsumingEnumerable()));
    }
}
```

Note that, for efficiency's sake, you could increase `MaxQueuedElementsPerCollection` to, say, `10` or `100` so that the consumers don't have to run in lock-step with each other.

There is one **problem with this code**, though.  When a collection is empty the consumer has to wait for the producer to produce an element, and when a collection is full the producer has to wait for the consumer to consume an element.  Consider what happens mid-way through the execution of your `tt => tt.Any(k => k > 5)` lambda...

1. The producer waits for the collection to be non-full and adds `5`.
2. The consumer waits for the collection to be non-empty and removes `5`.

   - `5 > 5` returns `false` and enumeration continues.
3. The producer waits for the collection to be non-full and adds `6`.
4. The consumer waits for the collection to be non-empty and removes `6`.

   - `6 > 5` returns `true` and enumeration stops.  `Any()`, the lambda, and the consumer task all return.
5. The producer waits for the collection to be non-full and adds `7`.
6. The producer waits for the collection to be non-full and...that never happens!

   - The consumer has already abandoned the enumeration, so it won't consume any elements to make room for the new one.  `Add()` will never return.

The cleanest way I could come up with to prevent this deadlock is to ensure the entire collection gets enumerated even if `func` doesn't do so.  This just requires a simple change to the `StartConsumerTask<>()` [local method](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/local-functions)...

```cs
Task<S> StartConsumerTask<S>(BlockingCollection<T> collection, Func<IEnumerable<T>, S> func)
{
    return Task.Run(
        () => {
            try
            {
                return func(collection.GetConsumingEnumerable());
            }
            finally
            {
                // Prevent BlockingCollection<>.Add() calls from
                // deadlocking by ensuring the entire collection gets
                // consumed even if func abandoned its enumeration early.
                foreach (T element in collection.GetConsumingEnumerable())
                {
                    // Do nothing...
                }
            }
        }
    );
}
```

The downside of this is that `tt` will always be enumerated to completion, even if *both* `tt1` and `tt2` abandon their enumerators early.

With that addressed, this...

```cs
static void Main()
{
    IEnumerable<int> mynums = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Trace("mynums:");

    Console.WriteLine("Both: (any > 5, sum) = {0}", mynums.Both(tt => tt.Any(k => k > 5), tt => tt.Sum()));
}
```

...outputs this...

```
mynums: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9.
Both: (any > 5, sum) = (True, 45)
```

Comment: This is excellent! I need to think about the problem you mentioned, though.

Answer (score 4):

The way you've written your computation model (i.e. `return (f1(tt), f2(tt))`) there is no way to avoid multiple iterations of your enumerable. You're basically saying compute `Item1` then compute `Item2`.

You have to either change the model from `(Func<IEnumerable<T>, S1>, Func<IEnumerable<T>, S2>)` to `(Func<T, S1>, Func<T, S2>)` or to `Func<IEnumerable<T>, (S1, S2)>` to be able to run the computations in parallel.

You implementation of `Any5Sum` is basically the second approach (`Func<IEnumerable<T>, (S1, S2)>`). But there's already a built-in method for that.

Try this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Aggregate: (any > 5, sum) = {0}",
    mynums
        .Aggregate<int, (bool any5, int sum)>(
            (false, 0),
            (a, x) => (a.any5 | x > 5, a.sum + x)));
```

Comment: Thanks. The `return (f1(tt), f2(tt))` is just one example implementation which, indeed, does iterate the `IEnumerable` twice. It obviously is possible to avoid iterating the `IEnumerable` twice since `Both_NonStream` does just that (although in way that I want to avoid). I think I'll just have to have a go at using threads to see if it's possible (or fail!).

Comment: @banbh - `Both_NonStream` doesn't avoid it. It just passes it from  `tt` (which you're watching) to `tt2` (which you're not). You're still getting two iterations, well, three in fact.

Comment: I don't think I did a good job of explaining what I'm looking for. I've added an edit with a (IMO) very operational definition of what I'm looking for (namely the bits in square brackets). I'm curious whether it's now clear.

Comment: It appears to me that at least all of the respondents found the question clear from the beginning.  Still, the code in this answer does (preemptively) satisfy the latter two requirements edited into the question: `mynums` is enumerated only once, with only one element "in-flight" at a time.  It doesn't meet requirement #1 of a specific method signature, but I think the point is that you don't need to invent your own method for this because [`Aggregate()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.aggregate) is it.

Comment: The shortcoming of my `Any5Sum` (as well using `Aggregate`) is that you need access to the source code of `f1` and `f2`! So, at least in my opinion, these approaches are at the wrong level of abstraction. Requirement #1 makes this clear (and the answer of  @BACON solves it at this level of abstraction).

Answer (score 0):

The core problem here is who is responsible for calling `Enumeration.MoveNext()` (eg by using a foreach loop). Synchronizing multiple foreach loops across threads would be slow and fiddly to get right.

Implementing `IAsyncEnumerable<T>`, so that multiple `await foreach` loops can take turns processing items would be easier. But still silly.

So the simpler solution would be to change the question. Instead of trying to call multiple methods that both try to enumerate the items, change the interface to simply visit each item.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is possible to satisfy all the requirements of the question, and one more (very natural) requirement, namely that the original enumerable be only enumerated partially if each of the two `Func<IEnumerable<T>, S>` consume it partially.
(This was discussed by @BACON). The approach is discussed in more detail in my [GitHub repo 'CoEnumerable'](https://github.com/banbh/CoEnumerable). The idea is that the [Barrier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.barrier) class provides a fairly straightforward approach to implement a proxy `IEnumerable` which can be consumed by each of the `Func<IEnumerable<T>, S>`s while the proxy consumes the real `IEnumerable` just once. In particular, the implementation consumes only as much of the original enumerable is as absolutely necessary (i.e., it satisfies the extra requirement mentioned above).

The proxy is:

```
class BarrierEnumerable<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    private Barrier barrier;
    private bool moveNext;
    private readonly Func<T> src;

    public BarrierEnumerable(IEnumerator<T> enumerator)
    {
        src = () => enumerator.Current;
    }

    public Barrier Barrier
    {
        set => barrier = value;
    }

    public bool MoveNext
    {
        set => moveNext = value;
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                barrier.SignalAndWait();
                if (moveNext)
                {
                    yield return src();
                }
                else
                {
                    yield break;
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            barrier.RemoveParticipant();
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
}
```

in terms of which we can combine the two consumers

```
public static T Combine<S, T1, T2, T>(this IEnumerable<S> source,
    Func<IEnumerable<S>, T1> coenumerable1,
    Func<IEnumerable<S>, T2> coenumerable2,
    Func<T1, T2, T> resultSelector)
{
    using var ss = source.GetEnumerator();
    var enumerable1 = new BarrierEnumerable<S>(ss);
    var enumerable2 = new BarrierEnumerable<S>(ss);
    using var barrier = new Barrier(2, _ => enumerable1.MoveNext = enumerable2.MoveNext = ss.MoveNext());
    enumerable2.Barrier = enumerable1.Barrier = barrier;
    using var t1 = Task.Run(() => coenumerable1(enumerable1));
    using var t2 = Task.Run(() => coenumerable2(enumerable2));
    return resultSelector(t1.Result, t2.Result);
}
```

The GitHub repo has a couple of examples of using the above code, and some brief design discussion (including limitations).